# Sequelize error with MariaDB

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mariadb, mariasql

I am trying to setup `sequelize` as ORM for my `MariaDB`.

Here is my setup:

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');

var db= new sequelize('dbname', 'user', 'pass', {
  dialect: 'mariadb'
});
```

When I run my app I get the following error :

```
/my/path/to/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:23
    throw new Error('Please install mysql package manually');
    ^

Error: Please install mysql package manually
```

Why is sequelize trying to connect to mysql rather than mariadb as I specified in the `dialect` directive? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequelize internally uses the same library to connect with MariaDB or MySQL , take a look to the documentation 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/ specifically in the section Installation.

To make it works you just need to install mysql package so:

```
$ npm install --save mysql2
```

Comment: I went through the docs a bazillion times...don't know how I didn't see that...thank you!!

Comment: `mysql2` required for current versions

Comment: @indospace.io If the answer is incorrect in your opinion either say so in the comments or post your own answer, but do not edit somebody else's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Sequelize now has the dialect `mariadb`, do not use `mysql`

```
npm install --save mariadb
npm install --save sequelize
```

Sequelize connection code...

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mariadb'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What the previous answer fails to mention is you must also set the dialect to MySQL...`dialect: mysql` because `dialect: mariadb` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You must install mysql or any dialect using -g.

```
npm i -g mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `yarn`:

```
yarn add mariadb
```